# Express & Firebase can't set header after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express, firebase

Following is my server using express framework and for the backhand there is firebase api

I have two problem i.e how come my function is getting called twice and what is the error

```
 app.get('/user/:userID/profile/edit', function(req, res) {
  var authData = ref.getAuth();
  var str = (req.query.message == undefined ? "" : req.query.message);
  if(authData) {
    if(req.params.userID == authData.uid){
      ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).on("value",function(snapshot) {
        var userData = snapshot.val();
        res.render('Profile/edit', {
          title : "Price Drop Alert",
          pagetitle : "Profile",
          firstname : userData.firstname,
          lastname : userData.lastname,
          dob : userData.dob,
          tel : userData.tel,
          email : userData.email,
          uid : authData.uid,
          message : str
        });
      });
    }
    else
      res.sendStatus(404);
  }
  else
    res.redirect('/?message='+encodeURIComponent("User is not logged in"));
});

app.post('/user/:userID/profile/edit', function(req,res) {
  var uid = req.params.userID;
  if(req.body.fsubmit == "Submit"){
    ref.child("users").child(uid).update({
      firstname : req.body.fname
    });
    console.log("update");
    res.redirect('/user/'+req.params.userID+"/profile/edit");
  }
});
```

following is the error that i get

```
  update
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:346:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/saunish/WebstormProjects/priceDrop/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:718:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/saunish/WebstormProjects/priceDrop/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:163:12)
    at done (/home/saunish/WebstormProjects/priceDrop/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:957:10)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/saunish/WebstormProjects/priceDrop/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:355:10)
    at View.render (/home/saunish/WebstormProjects/priceDrop/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:126:8)
    at tryRender (/home/saunish/WebstormProjects/priceDrop/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:639:10)
    at EventEmitter.render (/home/saunish/WebstormProjects/priceDrop/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:591:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/home/saunish/WebstormProjects/priceDrop/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:961:7)
    at /home/saunish/WebstormProjects/priceDrop/app.js:130:13
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:346:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/saunish/WebstormProjects/priceDrop/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:718:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/saunish/WebstormProjects/priceDrop/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:163:12)
    at done (/home/saunish/WebstormProjects/priceDrop/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:957:10)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/saunish/WebstormProjects/priceDrop/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:355:10)
    at View.render (/home/saunish/WebstormProjects/priceDrop/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:126:8)
    at tryRender (/home/saunish/WebstormProjects/priceDrop/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:639:10)
    at EventEmitter.render (/home/saunish/WebstormProjects/priceDrop/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:591:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/home/saunish/WebstormProjects/priceDrop/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:961:7)
    at /home/saunish/WebstormProjects/priceDrop/app.js:168:13
```

Comment: Same problem (no answer yet): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35507201/firebase-warning-exception-was-thrown-by-user-callback-error-cant-set-header

Comment: What is the need to use an Express server to proxy Firebase calls?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change method on() for once(), otherwise your callback function gets triggered every time there is an update to your data,

Answer (score 1):

Use `once` instead of `on` in this line:

```
ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).on("value",function(snapshot)
```

it should look like this:

```
ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).once("value",function(snapshot)
```

I had this problem today and this is how I fixed it.